# Using git and subversion code within a Bazaar project

Tags: git, svn, bazaar

I'm planning on tracking source with bzr but will be needing to include some clones and checkouts of other projects mine depends on.

Is there any advice beyond simply adding their directories to an ignore file and moving on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out the git and svn branches with Bazaar into the appropriate directories (using the [bzr-svn](https://launchpad.net/bzr-svn) and [bzr-git](https://launchpad.net/bzr-git) plugins). Then you can update or push everything in one go using the [bzr-externals](https://launchpad.net/bzr-externals) plugin.

But if you just wanted to manually use git and svn then yeah check it out with those tools and ignore the directories.

Comment: I don't really need to make commits against those projects.  I just want to be able to use them and check out their code without interfering with my own bzr-based stuff.

Comment: Sure, using externals will also allow you to pull/update everything in one go if that is something you need. Otherwise I don't see you needing anything more than manually checking them out in your tree.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is checkout from other version control systems into subdirectories of a bzr branch and not have bzr bug you about them, then the easiest solution is to add those subdirectories to your bzr branch's `.bzrignore` file.

Comment: As a followup question, is there any kind of trick I can do to set the version/tag of the svn/git repo so that fresh checkouts have the correct dependencies indicated?

Comment: For that you'll have to use a plugin like bzr-externals. bzr itself does not have support for that sort of dependency linking in the core yet.

Answer (score 0):

It should be better if you could provide more info about your projects, suck as it is a ant build or maven build project?

If you just want to ignore some depends projects, you can add them into .gitignore files like this

/project1
/project2
.....

Br,
Tim

Comment: I'm using bzr, not git.  Although my project is mostly Javascript based.